# Extracting filenames from a path MYSQL

Tags: mysql, string

Is there a simply select statement usign a combination of string functions to pull out a filename from a directory listing?

```
xxxx\xxxx\filename.txt
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is ideal for this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(myFileName, '\\', -1)
```

The last argument of `-1` says to return everything *after* the last `\`. Note that you have to escape the `\` as `\\`.

There's a working SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a043/1).

Comment: Generally it is correct but backslash escaping doesn't work. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/14544)

Comment: @juergend - Because your path [does not really contain slashes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/14550).

Comment: Works great - was trying to use the above with right() and wasn't working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks both! I'll add a working fiddle because the backslashes are so confusing.

Comment: On *unix it'll be: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(myFileName, '/', -1)`