# Need output of substring sql without using reverse

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query which is returning output; I need to get substring with last occurrence, I am confused and not able to find out how to do that:

```
SELECT
    spsetuppath,
    SUBSTRING(spsetuppath, 0, (LEN(spsetuppath) - CHARINDEX('\', RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(spsetuppath))))) + 1)
FROM
    UMRdb..sql_spversion 
WHERE
    bitversion = '64' 
    AND productversion = ' 10.50.2500.0'
```

Output of this command is as follows

[image]

For the last column, I need the path before exe and I need only exe file name - how to do that?

So output I am expecting should look like this

```
SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU.exe
```

Comment: One question. Why without reverse? In `SUBSTRING` don't use `0` as second parameter. You need to use `CHARINDEX('\', RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(spsetuppath))))) + 1`.

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17090237/1915746

Comment: @rokuto even if you use reverse output as you said iam not using 0 as second parameter 
select SUBSTRING(spsetuppath,CHARINDEX('\',rtrim(ltrim(reverse(spsetuppath)))),LEN(spsetuppath)) 
from UMRdb..sql_spversion where bitversion='64' and 
productversion=' 10.50.2500.0                                     ' its not giving me output ,

Comment: @user1915746 its saying substring_index is not valid builtin function, one you specified is for mysql i wonder why sql doesnt have any such function

Comment: @deepti Because it is mysql function, and you are (probably) using SQL SERVER 2008.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
SELECT
    spsetuppath,
    SUBSTRING(spsetuppath, CHARINDEX('\', RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(spsetuppath)))) - 1, 150)
FROM
    UMRdb..sql_spversion 
WHERE
    bitversion = '64' 
    AND productversion = ' 10.50.2500.0'
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(256) = '\\blablabla\dbms\MSSQL\SQL SERVER 2008\SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU.exe'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('\', RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(@string)))) - 1, 150)
```

**EDIT:** If you want to avoid `SUBSTRING` function use  this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(256) = '\\blablabla\dbms\MSSQL\SQL SERVER 2008\SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x64-ENU.exe'

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string),CHARINDEX('\', RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(@string)))) - 1))
```

Comment: @rokutu why 150 string can go as long as can

Comment: @deepti It does not matter. You can change it to `LEN(spsetuppath)` and it should work.

Comment: SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(spsetuppath),CHARINDEX('\', RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(spsetuppath)))) - 1)) 
 from UMRdb..sql_spversion where bitversion='64' and productversion=' 10.50.2500.0     not working thanks rokotu for trying

Answer (score 0):

select right(spsetuppath, charindex('\', reverse(spsetuppath) + '\') - 1)    from UMRdb..sql_spversion where bitversion='64' and 
productversion=' 10.50.2500.0                                     '

this worked awesome.